# POST a complex Json parameter

Tags: android, json

My JSON Parameter:

```
{
"params":{
    "model":"res.users",
    "method": "read",
    "args": [[907], ["name", "login", "image_small"]],
    "kwargs": {},
    "context": {
        "from_searchview": true
    }
}
```

I create a parameter class to post:

```
public class XPSCredsParamImage {
public XPSCredsParamImageDetail params;

public XPSCredsParamImage(String model, String method, String[][] args, String kwargs, Context context) {
    this.params = new XPSCredsParamImageDetail(model, method, args, kwargs, context);
}

public static class XPSCredsParamImageDetail {
    public String model;
    public String method;
    public String args[][];
    public String kwargs;
    public Context context;

    public XPSCredsParamImageDetail(String model, String method, String[][] args, String kwargs, Context context) {
        this.model = model;
        this.method = method;
        this.args = args;
        this.kwargs = kwargs;
        this.context = context;
    }
}

public class Context {
    public Boolean searchview;

    public Context(Boolean searchview) {
        this.searchview = searchview;
    }
}
```

This is my Interface:

```
public interface XPSApiEndpoint {

@POST("/web/dataset/call_kw")
Call<String> getImage(@Body XPSCredsParamImage param);
```

Now I use Async Task to post params and get data to a JSONObject:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            XPSApiEndpoint xps = XPSClient.getXPSClient();
            Call<String> call = xps.getImage(new XPSCredsParamImage());
            String response = null;
```

But I don't know how to write param in to xps.getImage(new XPSCredsParamImage());
My params is quite complex.
What I have to do?

Comment: you are passing empty `new XPSCredsParamImage()` object. You have to fill it with data before passing

Comment: Yeah I know, but my data params is so complex with me, I don't know how to fill that data.

Comment: Just pass the values you want to the constructor. Nobody except you knows which values you need to pass there.

Answer (score 0):

Your json data if not valid, you've forget about '}' at the end.

To create proper data model for your json you could use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/  - it helps you to create model by your json.

Then you should fill your model with data and send it via retrofit with @Body tag.